# Find gem remote source

Tags: github, rubygems

I can find the local install path of a gem by

```
> gem which oauth
/Users/xxjjnn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth.rb
```

And when using a Bundler you can specify the source of the git repo:

```
gem 'deadlock_retry', git: "https://github.com/mperham/deadlock_retry.git"
```

However, many gems in a gemfile do not specify a git source. When searching github for 'oauth' for example, many branches were returned. If the Gemfile does not specify a source, how do you deduce what the URI used to install it is?

Nether of these work:

```
gem specification oauth | grep github
bundle install | grep oauth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source isn't specified in a particular gem, it comes from the source specified in your Gemfile. At the top of your Gemfile you'll see something like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

Comment: Aha, and searching rubygems will always return only one result